# Git can't find the file though it is exist

Tags: git, github

Git can't find the file though it is exist

below is Git bash

```
$ git status
On branch WI
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/WI'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        csvTrainImages 13440x1024.csv

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

BC@DESKTOP-USA MIN ~/Documents/GitHub/A/data (WI)
$ git add csvTrainImages 13440x1024.csv
fatal: pathspec 'csvTrainImages' did not match any files
```

Comment: There's a space in your path... Escape it with a backslash or autocomplete the name with Tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's due to the space in the file name. So adding any such file where name is separated with space should be mentioned in the terminal as follows:

```
git add csvTrainImages\ 13440x1024.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to add the file(s):

```
git add .
```

where `.` is used to add files in the current folder/directory.

Or you could just type in the file name

ex:

```
git add xyz.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of space in your file name, better to use `Tab` to autocomplete or you can write it using backslash `\` like `git add csvTrainImages\ 13440x1024.csv`

or

try using `git add .`

Here `.` add all modified and untracked files in current directory.